# "Null" Foreign key relationship creating record on MVC3 + EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using EF + MVC3 + razor
I have my userProfile model class with a Name, Surname variables + a foreign key Hobby (as I want to see it as a dropdown)
I created a controler simply selecting this clase and Data Context.

When I try to create the record, it doesn’t let me, as it says in the validation area: "The Hobby field is required. " . 
I want the "Hobby" dropdown not to be required. 
How can I acomplish that?!..

This is what I have:

Model:

```
public class UserProfile    {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int HobbiesId { get; set; }
    public virtual Hobby Hobby { get; set; }}

public class Hobby
{
    public int HobbiesId { get; set; }
    public string HobbieName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; } 
}

 public class UserProfileDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hobby> Hobbies{ get; set; }
 }
```

View:

```
[..]@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>UserProfile</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HobbyId, "Hobby")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("HobbyId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>  model.HobbyIdId)
    </div>
[..]
```

The controller's create is:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserProfiles.Add(userprofile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.HobbyId = new SelectList(db.Hobbies, "HobbyId", "Hobby", userprofile.HobbyId);
 return View(userprofile); }
```

I already tried modifying:

```
 public class Hobby
{
    public int ?HobbiesId { get; set; }
```

but it didn't work.

Any help?..

Thanks in advance!..

PnP

Comment: Did you try `public int ?HobbiesId { get; set; }` inside your `UserProfile` class?

Comment: Also you should rename your `Hobby` class members to `Id` and `Name` instead of `HobbiesId` and `HobbyName`.  The `Id` member should not be nullable!

Comment: Try `public virtual Hobby? Hobby { get; set; }` in your UserProfile class.

Comment: HI. Thanks Yannick, yo are right. I tried with int ?HobbiesId { get; set; } and it worked!.. thank you very much!!..

Answer (score 1):

Add a foreign key constraint as shown below:

```
 public int? HobbiesId { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("HobbiesId")]
```